# How to Pass Different EventArgs to another sub

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET and I was experimenting with trying to call a `Sub` from another. I have the first `Sub` that handles a button then executes some code. I then want to call the other `Sub` I have that handles a rectangle being tapped. I'm having trouble call the second `Sub` from the first `Sub`. I think it might be the `EventArgs`. The first `Sub` is `RoutedEventsArgs` and the second is `TappedRoutedEventArgs`. I can't seem to find any documentation about this particular instance. I only see if it as the same `e`.

```
Public Class MainPage

    Private Sub Show_Message(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button_1.Click
        If Message.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed Then
            Message.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        Else
            Message.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
        End If

        ChangeColorItem_Click(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeColorItem_Click(sender As Object, e As TappedRoutedEventArgs) Handles Rectangle.Tapped

        'Change fill color to red to blue and back 
        If rectangleFill.Color = (Windows.UI.Colors.Red) Then
            rectangleFill.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue
        Else
            rectangleFill.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Red
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want it so that if `Show_Message` is run also run the `ChangeColorItem_Click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoutedEventArgs is a square peg, TappedRoutedEventArgs is a round hole... you're trying to put a square peg in a round hole... and you don't need to.

Unless there's a need for the event args, and I don't see the event args being used, you're better off putting the code into their own sub and simply calling it.

```
Public Class MainPage

    Private Sub Show_Message(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button_1.Click
        ShowMessage()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeColorItem_Click(sender As Object, e As TappedRoutedEventArgs) Handles Rectangle.Tapped

        ChangeColorItem()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowMessage()
        If Message.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed Then
            Message.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
        Else
            Message.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
        End If

        ChangeColorItem()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeColorItem()
        'Change fill color to red to blue and back 
        If rectangleFill.Color = (Windows.UI.Colors.Red) Then
            rectangleFill.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue
        Else
            rectangleFill.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Red
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind in the future. I am just learning VB.Net, I come from a VBA background. My work has tasked me with making a new program from the ground up. I wanted to see how to make the two subs work together to reduce duplicate code for future code.

Comment: I did get to work the way I described by using the     ChangeColorItem_Click(Nothing, Nothing)    that some else suggested by deleting the     Handles Button_1.Click

Comment: Those do work, as does creating a New TappedRoutedEventArggs and passing it in... but many wold consider all of those options poor coding practices and would fail most code reviews.